# Visual Studio 2012 compared to Visual Studio 2010 (delta)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a resource out there, which lists the delta Visual Studio 2012 <-> Visual Studio 2010 concerning new features etc...especially in the area of C# (not the language itself but the tools, like editor/debugger etc.) ? I have not found one @ MSDN.

That would be quite handy during the upgrade to VS 2012 in our team.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MSDN has this info now, though maybe not in a side-by-side comparison format:

[What's New in Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx)
[What's New for Visual C# in Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156499.aspx)
[Visual C# Breaking Changes in Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/hh678682)

You can see MSDN blogger Jason Zander's [top 12 reasons to upgrade](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/08/15/visual-studio-2012-and-net-framework-4-5-released-to-the-web.aspx).

And a [slideshow showing new features](http://www.eweek.com/developer/slideshows/visual-studio-2012-rtm-comes-chock-full-of-enhancements/) focusing on Win8/XAML/LightSwitch.

Also, the price of VS Professional [has been lowered](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/pricing) from US$799 to US$499 (there's no longer an upgrade option for this version).

The available project types may be interesting to some:
[Comparison Chart: New Project Types Visual Studio 11 vs. Visual Studio 10](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2012/02/29/chart-visual-studio-11-vs-vs-10-vs-common-project-types.aspx)

Comment: Also useful - compatibility matrix here http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compatibility and note if you target Windows XP applications, you can't remote debug from 2012 any more.

Answer (score 2):

One good reason not to upgrade until really ready or this "feature" is fixed - [Linq to EF Join throws "Index was out of range" after upgrade from VS2010 to VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12489749/198032)

Comment: Seems it is fixed now: Seems it is fixed now: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763986/linq-to-ef-join-throws-index-was-out-of-range-after-upgrade-from-vs2010-to-vs2012