# Linq to EF Join throws "Index was out of range" after upgrade from VS2010 to VS2012

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, exception, visual-studio-2012

After upgrading from Visual Studio 2010 to 2012 code started throwing "ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index" on Linq queries using Joins.

The following simple example made in LINQPad (using an EF data model) gives me the ArgumentOutOfRangeException:

```
void Main()
{
    var iq1 = Customers.Select(ap => ap.ID);
    var iq2 = iq1.Join(Customers.Select(ap => ap.ID),
                    a => a,
                    b => b,
                    (a, b) => new { a });

    iq2.Dump(); 
}
```

Changing the previous example to return an anonymous object containing both sides of the join doesn't give the ArgumentOutOfRangeException and gives results as expected:

```
void Main()
{
    var iq1 = ActionPlans.Select(ap => ap.ID);
    var iq2 = iq1.Join(ActionPlans.Select(ap => ap.ID),
                    a => a,
                    b => b,
                    (a, b) => new { a, b });

    iq2.Dump(); 
}
```

Ok, so for some reason I had to return both sides of the join, but then I tried the following example using a dummy value instead, that also executed without a problem:

```
void Main()
{
    var iq1 = ActionPlans.Select(ap => ap.ID);
    var iq2 = iq1.Join(ActionPlans.Select(ap => ap.ID),
                    a => a,
                    b => b,
                    (a, b) => new { a, x = 1 });

    iq2.Dump(); 
}
```

Taking the first example and adding a ToList() to the first query also makes it execute without a problem:

```
void Main()
{
    var iq1 = ActionPlans.Select(ap => ap.ID).ToList();
    var iq2 = iq1.Join(ActionPlans.Select(ap => ap.ID),
                    a => a,
                    b => b,
                    (a, b) => new { a });

    iq2.Dump(); 
}
```

**Important:** Trying the first query on a workstation without the Visual Studio 2012 upgrade works fine!

Can anyone confirm/explain this new "feature"? :-)

Comment: This bug has been filed at [Linq to EF Join throws “Index was out of range” after upgrade from VS2010 to VS2012](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763986/linq-to-ef-join-throws-index-was-out-of-range-after-upgrade-from-vs2010-to-vs2012). If you can reproduce it, then tell Microsoft. If a fix is important to you, then "upvote" it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erwin, just to close the loop on this: We have confirmed that it is a bug we introduced recently in LINQ to Entities and we are looking at ways to get a fix out. Thanks a lot for reporting it!

Comment: hey @divenga .. any updates regarding this issue?
Our whole project is stopped after the team upgraded to VS2012!

Comment: We're working to getting a fix to this bug shipped, along with a couple of others. I'm not sure if it is plausible, but as you discovered, adding a second dummy property to the anonymous type will work around the issue.

Comment: hey @alaasdk could you contact us on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com? I want to help unblocked your team.

Comment: Seems it is fixed now: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/763986/linq-to-ef-join-throws-index-was-out-of-range-after-upgrade-from-vs2010-to-vs2012

Answer (score 4):

After giving this some more investigation, I've come to the conclusion that the problem is the anonymous class I'm returning from the Linq query, I think it isn't allowed anymore to return an anonymous class with only one field in it, I know it isn't needed to wrap the field in an anonymous class but ... as I said this worked before upgrading.

Following example gives me the "ArgumentOutOfRangeException - Index was out of range":

```
void Main()
{
    var iq1 = ActionPlans.Select(ap => ap.ID).ToList();
    var iq2 = iq1.Join(ActionPlans.Select(ap => ap.ID),
                    a => a,
                    b => b,
                    (a, b) => new { a });

    iq2.Dump();
}
```

this next example works as expected:

```
void Main()
{
    var iq1 = ActionPlans.Select(ap => ap.ID).ToList();
    var iq2 = iq1.Join(ActionPlans.Select(ap => ap.ID),
                    a => a,
                    b => b,
                    (a, b) => a );

    iq2.Dump();
}
```